# How do I efficiently parse a substring in a Pandas Dataframe based on a value in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume, I have the following table:

```
random_string|end_location|substring
-------------|------------|---------
HappyBirthday|     4      |Happ
GoodBye      |     5      |GoodB
NaN          |    NaN     |NaN
Haensel      |     2      |Ha
...          |     ...    |...
```

This table represents the desired output. The initial input are just the first 2 columns. The question is: How do I get there elegantly? Rows without content should not be processed.

I tried the following:

```
df['random_string'].str[0:4] or [0:5]
```

The problem with this approach is that ALL strings will be cut to the same length which is not the desired outcome.

I tried:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    end = int(row[1]['end_location'])
    df.loc[row[0], 'substring'] = row[1]['random_substring'][0:end]
```

This works but I feel is rather unelegant and inefficient. (How) (C/)can the above be performed in a more elegant - perhaps vectorized way. Maybe something with apply could work?

Comment: This is a neat question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df

   random_string  end_location
0  HappyBirthday           4.0
1        GoodBye           5.0
2            NaN           NaN
3        Haensel           2.0
```

Work with subset

```
d1 = df.dropna()
rs = d1.random_string.values.tolist()
el = d1.end_location.values.astype(int).tolist()  # Thx @MaxU for `astype(int)`
df.loc[d1.index, 'substring'] = [s[:n] for s, n in zip(rs, el)]

   random_string  end_location substring
0  HappyBirthday           4.0      Happ
1        GoodBye           5.0     GoodB
2            NaN           NaN       NaN
3        Haensel           2.0        Ha
```

---

***Timing***

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

%%timeit
mask = (df['random_string'].str.len() >= 0) & (df['end_location'] >= 0)
df.loc[mask, 'substring'] = [t[0][:int(t[1])] for t in df[mask].values.tolist()]
10 loops, best of 3: 26.1 ms per loop

%%timeit
d1 = df.dropna()
rs = d1.random_string.values.tolist()
el = d1.end_location.values.astype(int).tolist()
df.loc[d1.index, 'substring'] = [s[:int(n)] for s, n in zip(rs, el)]
10 loops, best of 3: 21.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: you can make it even faster: `el = d1.end_location.astype(int).values.tolist()` and then `df.loc[d1.index, 'substring'] = [s[:n] for s, n in zip(rs, el)]` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]:
   random_string  end_location
0  HappyBirthday           4.0
1        GoodBye           5.0
2            NaN           NaN
3        Haensel           2.0

In [25]: mask = (df['random_string'].str.len() >= 0) & (df['end_location'] >= 0)

In [26]: df[mask]
Out[26]:
   random_string  end_location
0  HappyBirthday           4.0
1        GoodBye           5.0
3        Haensel           2.0

In [27]: df.loc[mask, 'substring'] = [t[0][:int(t[1])] for t in df[mask].values.tolist()]

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
   random_string  end_location substring
0  HappyBirthday           4.0      Happ
1        GoodBye           5.0     GoodB
2            NaN           NaN       NaN
3        Haensel           2.0        Ha
```

**Timing** for a larger (40K rows) DF

```
In [179]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [40]: %%timeit
    ...: mask = (df['random_string'].str.len() >= 0) & (df['end_location'] >= 0)
    ...: [t[0][:int(t[1])] for t in df[mask].values.tolist()]
    ...:
10 loops, best of 3: 77.3 ms per loop

In [41]: df.shape
Out[41]: (40000, 2)
```

Comment: That's fast! This works if every row is filled. What about when I want to execute the operations only on rows that have content? I was trying to indicate that in the table above but did not manage to explicitly state it like that. Sorry!

Comment: @Thornhale, `"only on rows that have content"` - what column do you mean? Could you edit your question and put there a reproducible data set?

Comment: Ok, content updated. Rows that have NaN in any of the columns should not be processed.